# python: .py file icon problem in version 3.9.0

Tags: python

I had python installed on my device, everything was running perfectly, when I save a 'file.py' it shows the default python icon (the blue and yellow snakes) and it is clear that this is a python file.
I made a factory reset of the device for many reasons, then i reinstalled python and pip, everything working fine and I'm now running python 3.9.0, except that now the 'file.py' has a blank icon (the white, empty one) and I cannot run it on cmd.
I don't know what is wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What won't run on cmd? Python command or the .py file?
If the python command isn't recognized on cmd then probably Python is not set in your device's env variable PATH;
I think once you choose Python as default application to open .py files, the python icon will appear on .py files.